# WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 issue with form-data resource API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a API backend which requires to pass form-data, it works in postman, but after implementation in WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 it didn't work.

This is my OpenAPI definition:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: OpenStack
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: /
security:
  - default: []
paths:
  /webServiceOpenStack/project_create.php:
    post:
      tags:
        - Créer un compte client
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
        description: ''
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                name:
                  type: string
                description:
                  type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
      security:
        - default: []
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      x-auth-type: Application & Application User
      x-wso2-application-security:
        security-types:
          - oauth2
        optional: false
```

This is a screenshot of postman response:

[image]

This is a screenshot of API manager response:

[image]

The error in response body means that the backend didn't get the form-data that I send it.